# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'prophet' in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, modulenotfounderror, facebook-prophet

prophet was working fine in VS code in a virtual environment. I need to switch to jupyter notebook. I start the kernel in the same virtual environment.

```
from prohpet import Prophet
```

gives the following error

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_13320/2493871459.py in <module>
----> 1 from prophet import Prophet

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'prophet'
```

the list of installed modules :
[image: pip list]

Comment: If you'd rather not sort out why the installed version isn't being seen, try running `%pip install prophet` in a cell in the notebook where you want to use it. Restart the kernel and try the import statement.